# pandas match two columns and create another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with A ,B ,C columns.I want to compare B and C columns and create two columns Which are A-1(current row year -1) and A-2(current row year -2) where A is year column.

Example : In the dataframe for the year 1971 ,the B column has apple , orange
and C column has only apple and year 1970 has B -banana,apple and C-apple.
Now , for each row in the year 1971 we try to generate values for A-1(1970) , A-2(1969) column .In year (A-1)1970 , apple is captured in both B,C columns so we flag yes for first two rows of 1971 year then for third row it is flagged as no as there is no orange in the year 1970.

So for every row we consider the year(say 1971) and check the B  and C values and see whether that particular B value is also captured in C column in the year-1(1970) and year-2(1969 , in this case it will be nan as we dont any record with 1969 in our dataframe) and flag them accordingly.

dataframe  :

```
 A          B          C       D
1971       apple    apple      yes
1971       apple    apple      yes
1971       orange   nan        no
1970       banana   nan        no
1970       apple    apple      yes
1972       mango    mango      yes
1972       banana   banana     yes
1972       orange   orange     yes
1972       apple    apple      yes
1973       banana    nan       no
1973       mango     mango     yes
1973       apple     nan       no
1974       orange    nan       no
```

output:

```
 A          B          C       A-1    A-2
1971       apple    apple      yes    nan
1971       apple    apple      yes    nan
1971       orange   nan        no     nan
1970       banana   nan        nan    nan
1970       apple    apple      nan    nan
1972       mango    mango      no     no 
1972       banana   banana     no     no
1972       orange   orange     no     no
1972       apple    apple      no     no
1973       banana    nan       yes    no
1973       mango     mango     yes    no
1973       apple     nan       yes    yes
1974       orange    nan       no     yes
```

i cant figure out , please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1971,1971,1971,1970,1970,1972,1972,1972,1972,1973,1973,1973,1974], 
     'B': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange'],
     'C': ['apple', 'apple', 'nan', 'nan', 'apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'nan', 'mango', 'nan', 'nan'],
    })

fruits_by_year = df[df.C!='nan'].groupby('A')['C'].apply(set).to_dict()

def get_A_minus_n(x, n):
    if x.A-n not in fruits_by_year:
        return 'nan'
    elif x.B in fruits_by_year[x.A-n]:
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return 'no'

df['A-1'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_A_minus_n(x, 1), axis=1)
df['A-2'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_A_minus_n(x, 2), axis=1)
```

Let's first build a dict named `fruits_by_year`:

1. discard the rows whose `'C'` is `'nan'`
2. group by column `'A'` and get their values in column `'C'`
3. convert the values into a set
4. convert the whole results to a dict

It should be:

> {1970: {'apple'},  1971: {'apple'},  1972: {'apple', 'banana',
>   'mango', 'orange'},  1973: {'mango'}}

And then build up the two new columns. We need to:

1. build a function `get_A_minus_n` that returns different value in 3 different cases
2. apply that function to each row of the DataFrame

Note: the 9th row's `'A-1'`, `'A-2'` should be `'yes'`, `'yes'`